# jade template conditional class nodejs expressjs

Tags: node.js, templates, express, pug

I have a jade template file for my header and uses bootstrap markup. Depending on what page the user is on, the navigation bar needs to add class .active to that nav item. What is the best way to do this avoiding long code like this.

**header.jade**

```
if nav=='home'
   li.active
      a(href="/") Home
else
   li
      a(href='/') Home
if nav=='about'
   li.active
      a(href='/about') About
else
   li
      a(href='/about') About
```

**route**

```
router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
   res.render('about', { nav:'about' });
});
```

Notice how if there are many more links in the header, it will get much longer. Is there a better method to add class 'active' to the page that is being viewed?

Thanks
Tyler

Comment: Is this navbar all hardcoded?  can you refactor to use a loop instead?  There are some options in that direction...

Comment: Hi, generally yes it's hardcoded.. but will change once a user has signed in.. don't know of that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a mixin that handles the rendering of a list item.  This way your logic code does not have to be repeated:

```
mixin header-item(name, url)
  if name.toLowerCase() == nav
    li.active
      a(href=url)= name
  else
    li
      a(href=url)= name

+header-item('Home', '/')
+header-item('About', '/about')
```