# Jade conditional with select options

Tags: node.js, pug

How to set the `option` (of `select`) to `selected` to match the current language of the page?  Is there a way to inline it and simplify it something like this:

`(value="en" #{Locale}==='en' ? ',selected="selected"': '')`

I have tried some answers on this site, but they do not seem to work. Thank you.

This is the view:

```
 if(#{Locale} ==='en')
     option(value="en", selected="selected") #{English}
     option(value="bg") #{Bulgarian}
  else if(#{Locale} === 'bg')
     option(value="en") #{English}
     option(value="bg",selected="selected") #{Bulgarian}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24455987/142162), you could create a mix-in that handles the logic for you:

```
mixin lang-option(code, name)
  if (Locale === code)
    option(value=code, selected="selected")= name
  else
    option(value=code)= name

+lang-option('en', English)
+lang-option('bg', Bulgarian)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works if you need to parameterize the 'disabled' attribute as well.  Jade will not output attributes that evaluate to false.

```
//Selects the option when option.value == selectValue
mixin selectOption(option, selectValue)
  option(value=option.value, disabled=option.disabled, selected=(option.value==selectValue))= option.label
```